# Why are some LLMs trained on both CommonCrawl and Wikipedia/StackExchange?

Tags: large-language-models, training-datasets

Some LLMs are trained on both CommonCrawl and Wikipedia/StackExchange. Why? Does CommonCrawl already contain Wikipedia/StackExchange?

E.g., from the [LLaMa 1 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.13971.pdf):

[image]

and from https://huggingface.co/datasets/togethercomputer/RedPajama-Data-1T:

| Dataset | Token Count |
| --- | --- |
| Commoncrawl | 878 Billion |
| C4 | 175 Billion |
| GitHub | 59 Billion |
| Books | 26 Billion |
| ArXiv | 28 Billion |
| Wikipedia | 24 Billion |
| StackExchange | 20 Billion |
| Total | 1.2 Trillion |

Looking at https://commoncrawl.github.io/cc-crawl-statistics/plots/domains, it seems that CommonCrawl includes the Wikipedia and StackExchange domains. But maybe it's incomplete?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is a vanishingly small % of the internet. According to the information in the screenshot you posted, Wikipedia comprises less than 0.2% of the Common Crawl. A random sample of Common Crawl is extremely unlikely to have a meaningful amount of Wikipedia text.

Also, even if a Common Crawl segment does contain Wikipedia, it's still good to include it as a separate component. High quality factual information should be upsampled to achieve the best performance, as the repeated exposure to facts increases a LLM's ability to answer those factual questions correctly.